# Is Carlini-Wagner dependent on the network under attack?

Tags: neural-networks, adversarial-attacks

In my understanding, black-box attacks such as Carlini-Wagner are, in contrast to white-box attacks like FGSM, independent of the classifier's parameters, but various sources seem to disagree with this. What is the black-box aspect of Carlini-Wagner? And, if it is indeed not dependent on the classifier's parameters, is there a dataset such as Cifar-10 available with CW readily applied?